# My boolean value is false even though all the code is correct

Tags: c#, mysql

About my Program:

My algorithm(this class) is meant to check whether a delivery has been finished and afterwards makes the truck/trailer/driver available for another delivery, at the same time this algorithm sends another truck/trailer/driver on a delivery. To sum it up this class does the following:

- Check whether a booking is in Allocation mode (Allocation mode basically means that the "booking" is in progress of being delivered
- Check whether there is tonnage left of the booking (Ex. I want to sent 500 ton to a place, but a delivery can only be 30 ton at a time so it checks if there is still ton that needs to be delivered)
- To make the Driver(s)/Truck(s)/Trailer(s) available that finished their delivery.
- To automatically allocate tonnage to a Driver/Trailer/Truck.
- Deleting entries that are finished (any bookings that are finished - Logs still stay in the database).

My Problem:

I have no idea what is wrong with my class, I have been hours at it and can't seem to figure out what is causing my boolean variable (forLoopBreak) to trigger a "false" value when it is calling the method checkAvailTrailers(). The problem seems to be in there but I can't figure out what causes the problem.

Class:

```
[https://pastebin.com/4up8eppd][1]
```

( I couldn't paste it here as I met the limit of characters)

Notes:

- I know my programming looks but, but I am still new to this.
- I decided to attach the whole class as the problem may be at a different place.

Edit:

My code is too large to investigate so here is the relevant parts:

```
private void startAlgo()
{

                  checkAvailTrailers();
                        if (forloopBreak == false)
                        {
                            setErrorMessage("Avail Trailers not enough!");
                        }
}
```

private void checkAvailTrailers()
    {

```
    string trailerRouteAllocation = null;
    string trailerVragAllocation = null;
    string tempHolderTrailer = null;
    string myNewTempT = null;
    string trailermyTemp = null;

    int trailerCount = 0;
    int tempTra = -1;

    //Gets trailer route classification
    using (SqlCommand selectTrailer = new SqlCommand("SELECT [TR_Routes] FROM dbo.TrailerDetail  WHERE [TR_Allocation] = " + 0, con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = selectTrailer.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                trailerRouteAllocation = reader.GetString(0);
                tempHolderTrailer = trailerRouteAllocation;
                myNewTempT = trailerRouteAllocation;

                for (int l = 0; l < tempHolderTrailer.Length; l++)
                {
                    tempTra = myNewTempT.IndexOf(",");
                    if (tempTra >= 0)
                    {
                        trailermyTemp = myNewTempT.Substring(0,tempTra);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        trailermyTemp = myNewTempT;
                        if (trailermyTemp == myCurrentBookingRoute.ToString())
                        {
                            mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[trailerCount] = tempHolderTrailer;
                        }
                        break;

                    }
                    myNewTempT = myNewTempT.Substring(tempTra + 1);
                    if (trailermyTemp == myCurrentBookingRoute.ToString())
                    {
                        mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[trailerCount] = trailerRouteAllocation;
                    }
                }
                trailerCount++;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    //gets trailer vrag classification.
    int countTrailerVrag = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute.Length; l++)
    {
        if (mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] != null)
        {
            using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select [TR_Classification] FROM dbo.TrailerDetail WHERE [TR_Routes] = '" + mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] + "' AND [TR_Allocation] = " + 0, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader readerS = select.ExecuteReader())
                {
                        while (readerS.Read())
                        {
                            trailerVragAllocation = readerS.GetString(0);
                            myAvailableTrailerVragClassification[countTrailerVrag] = trailerVragAllocation;
                            countTrailerVrag++;
                        }
                        readerS.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int countTrailers = 0;
    string trailerRegNum = null;
    for (int l = 0; l < mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute.Length; l++)
    {
        if (mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] != null)
        {
            using (SqlCommand selectT = new SqlCommand("Select [TR_RegNumber] FROM dbo.TrailerDetail WHERE [TR_Routes] = '" + mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] + "'" + " AND [TR_Classification] = '" + myAvailableTrailerVragClassification[l] + "' AND [TR_Allocation] = " + 0, con))
            {
                 SqlDataReader readerT = selectT.ExecuteReader();
                    if (readerT.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (readerT.Read())
                        {
                            trailerRegNum = readerT.GetString(0);
                            myAvailableCurrentTraillerRegNumber[countTrailers] = trailerRegNum;
                            countTrailers++;
                        } 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        forloopBreak = false;
                    }
                readerT.Close();
            }
        }
    }//END OF TRAILER CHECKING

    //gets trailer's max tonnage
    int myTrailerTonMax = 0;
    int myTrailerTon = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute.Length; l++)
    {
        if (mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] != null)
        {
            using (SqlCommand selectT = new SqlCommand("Select [TR_MaxTonnage] FROM dbo.TrailerDetail WHERE [TR_Routes] = '" + mycurrentTrailerAvailableRoute[l] + "'" + " AND [TR_Classification] = '" + myAvailableTrailerVragClassification[l] + "'", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader readerS = selectT.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (readerS.Read())
                    {
                        myTrailerTon = readerS.GetInt32(0);
                        myTrailerAvailableTonMax[myTrailerTonMax] = myTrailerTon;
                        myTrailerTonMax++;
                    }
                    readerS.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extra:
- The data in my database matches the criteria, the while loop even executes but in the end my boolean value returns a false.

Comment: Your code is too large for us to investigate, can't you just post the relevant bits?

Comment: I will try to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readerT.HasRows` clause will always be true if there is any data initially in the reader. Here is the property's description from the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets a value that indicates whether the SqlDataReader contains one or more rows.

What you want to do instead (I assume) is set `forloopBreak = false;` when the `while` loop is finished. So inside the using block you put this:

```
SqlDataReader readerT = selectT.ExecuteReader();
while (readerT.Read())
{
     trailerRegNum = readerT.GetString(0);
     myAvailableCurrentTraillerRegNumber[countTrailers] = trailerRegNum;
     countTrailers++;
} 
forloopBreak = false;
readerT.Close();
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: You're right! This was the problem it seems, thanks!